Coupon collector inside the coupon collector
Consider the coupon collector problem, in which $n$ coupons must be collected and one coupon appears randomly daily.
It is well-known that it takes an average of $n H_n$ days to collect all coupons, where $H_n$ is the n-th harmonic number. My question is the following:
Suppose I remove all coupons that appear only once - call these singleton coupons. It is known there are $H_n$ of them on average, see here. After removing these singleton coupons, I take a look at how long it takes to collect all non-singleton coupons in the shortest sequence needed. What is this number?
To make things clearer, if the coupons are $[1,2,\ldots,10]$, one sequence could be
 3     9     4    10     9     9     7     6     7     2    10     7    10     9     8     3     5     9     9     3     8     1

In this case, the singletons are
 1     2     4     5     6

and the shortest (sub)sequence to collect all other coupons is
 3     9    10     9     9     7     7    10     7    10     9     8

with length 12, which is what we are interested in.
Here is a second example. Consider the coupons being the integers from 1 to 9. The sequence could be
 3     1     3     1     1     6     8     7     3     1     4     7     9     2     6     2     3     8     3     4     5

The singletons are
 5     9

The shortest subsequence is
 3     1     3     1     1     6     8     7     3     1     4     7     2

and its length, size or number of elements is 13 (down from 21).
Here is a third example, when the coupons are integers from 1 to 5
 3     1     4     1     5     4     4     5     2

The set of singletons is
 2     3

The subsequence without singletons is
 1     4     1     5

and its length is 4.
What is the length of the subsequence on average?
For $n=100$, the length of this subsequence is 376 using simulations, and for $n=200$ is 898. Is there a way to derive a simple formula using known results?
Edit: I have found that collecting $n-round(H_n)$ coupons (i.e. those that are left) out of a total of $n$ coupons takes me on average $n(\sum_{i=1}^{round(H_n)} \frac{1}{n-i+1})$.

Do all "shortest sequences" start at the beginning or not?  If singletons have been removed at the beginning, do we still count from the beginning or do we count from where the non-singletons start? // At the end, shall we presume you mean expected lengths?

We count from where mom singletons start and yes, we're looking at the expected length.

"Mom" singletons?

We count from where singletons start and we are looking at the expected length. I added a second example to clarify things.

The second example does not illustrate these issues and "count from where singletons start" further confuses it by suggesting a third method of determining length!  // Shorter, simpler examples might help.

Third example added now

Thank you -- that is helpful.
